# Dynamically created fileinput does not bind to change event on IE

Tags: jquery, file, internet-explorer, event-handling, jquery-events

I need to created fileinput elements dynamically.

Problem: I can't bind to the change event on IE.
Tried

```
.change(function(){});
.bind('click',function(){});
.on('click', function(){});
```

See my Codepen for demonstration:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwmxvp

```
<a href="#" id="fileInput">Click me</a>

$('#fileInput').click(function(){
      var fileSelector = document.createElement("input");
      fileSelector.setAttribute('type', 'file');
      
      fileSelector.click();
      $(fileSelector).change(function (e) {
        alert("file changed");
      });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be an IE security issue. You cannot trigger a fileupload button click. The user needs to actually click the upload button.

I had this problem when i tried to style the browse button for the upload, what i ended up doing was having the input on top of a styled button using position relative and opacity: 0, so the user was actually clicking the file upload input instead of the button.

```
[type=file]
{
    opacity:0;
    position: relative;
    left: -63px;
    width: 58px;
}
```

Fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/DSARd/1914/

P.S. If this code works for you in IE the problem might be that the element is not added to the dom. Try replacing your javascript with this

```
$('#fileInput').click(function(){
  var fileSelector = document.createElement("input");
  fileSelector.setAttribute('type', 'file');
  fileSelector.setAttribute('hidden', 'true');
  $("body").append(fileSelector);
  fileSelector.click();

  $(fileSelector).change(function (e) {
    alert("file changed");
  });
})
```

Comment: that is actually not right. The click event itself fires, the dialog appears. I only need to bind to the change event properly

Comment: your code works for me in Chrome but not IE, try this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/DSARd/1914/ as i said if you place and invisible file upload on top of your link this will work and the user will be none the wiser